# UIButton action exception in iphone

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I am using this code to move back to tableview but it gives error

but when i use

```
[self.navigationController pushViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

it works but not working with **popViewController**

```
CategoriesList*targetController=[[CategoriesList alloc]init];
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got the correct method signature if all you want is to pop the view controller at top of the stack. What is the error? Try this then:

```
 [self.navigationController popToViewController:targetController animated:YES];
```

From docs:

```
- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated
```

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 1):

@Jolly good was almost correct

Change:

```
[self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
```

to

```
[self.navigationController popToViewController:targetController animated:YES];
```